# Javascript: DataTables custom search box doesn't keep the 'X' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/9/

Trying to put the search box of DataTables in a `<div>`.

Html:

```
<div class="dataTables_filter">
<input type="text" id="dataTables_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
</div>
```

Script:

```
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
 $('#dataTables_filter').keyup(function(){
  oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );
 })
```

I saw this from another stack overflow post , but unfortunately the little 'X' button on the right of the search box doesn't show when you start typing in the box. Any way around this ? Perhaps i am using the wrong class on my `<input>` or `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the *little `x`* yourself, it's not something that magically appears, unless you're using Internet Explorer.

---

### Edit:

Since datatables creates this search box, You need to use [`fnInitComplete`](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/34/fninitcomplete-exists-or-just-a-myth) callback/function in datatables to target this search field, then you initialize this button.

You can see a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/20/

---

### Edit:

You're referring to the behavior in Chrome for `input type=search`

Just change the input type from `text` to `search` and it will do this behavior in Chrome.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/23/

Comment: the question is how will i add the little `x`, this is why i opened a question... the original box does have the x, the other one doesnt

Comment: i am not trying to recreate the functionality of 'X',  i am trying to use it from DataTable's code

Comment: Read the first line in my answer. Show me an example where Datatables has this feature built-in

Comment: if Datatables dont have this feature built in , how do they use it ? it should be somewhere in the .css in the correct <div> or something

Comment: Who is they? Show me where *they* use it

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/examples/index  every example uses the 'x' , its either in the .css , the .js or the .html  file

Comment: I don't see an x in any of them.  Are you using ie?

Comment: i use google chrome , how would i be using the 'x' myself in my jsfiddle if datatables didnt provide me with the `x`'s functionality (Edit: there is no .png with 'x' icon ) and i see the `x` in every example in both google chrome and internet explorer , just checked

Comment: Ok, this is functionality in google chrome, i was using ff, it's because the input is defined as `search` not `text`. So change your `input type=search` from `text` and it will do this behavior in chrome.

Comment: now, how will i actually remove the second search box and keep only the first one i made?

Answer (score 0):

Should your div class be dataTables_wrapper, not _filter, perhaps?

Comment: you can try it on fiddle and you will see that it doesn't work

Comment: I just did so now, but still it seems to be the intention. It's called _wrapper after all.